# Why are the elements in Stellar.js not moving?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 circles in the header that are suppose to fall at different rates when scrolled via stellar.js; unfortunatly, they dont even move.  They all have position attributes(absolute);
Moreover, I've applied the`data-stellar-ratio` to the approprate tags.  Why won't stellar.js work? Even further, how does one test for jQuery to know if it's just not pilot error?

**HTML**

```
<div id="companyInfo" >
    <div class="circlefront" data-stellar-ratio="1.2"></div>
    <div class="circlemiddle" data-stellar-ratio="1.8"></div>
    <div class="circlerear" data-stellar-ratio="3"></div>
    <div class="infoWrapper">
      <h1>Towing, you can't do it without a truck, i have a truck</h1>
      <p>Id abunum ta inte publicae adhui senterem praties tantiena quitas vis, factum destus. Loca vehebus; et? Ti. Upionem, sil tala morbit ina, nique confendum tati et acepsen ihilin sula audactorips, fatur ia consign arisulos inatuis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
section#company div#companyInfo {
  height: 24em;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
}
section#company div#companyInfo div.infoWrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 5em auto;
  text-align: center;
}
section#company div#companyInfo div.infoWrapper h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
section#company div#companyInfo div.infoWrapper p {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 1.125em;
}
section#company .circlefront {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 400px;
}
section#company .circlemiddle {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
}
section#company .circlerear {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  right: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
<script src="asset/js/libs/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
            $.stellar({
                horizontalScrolling: false,
                verticalOffset: 0,
            });
        });
</script>
```

*resources*
[stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/)
[tutorial on using stellar.js](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/)

Comment: If you look in the live sample code you can see that stellar js is linked in the correct place.

Comment: As an aside, those selectors are unnecessarily verbose. `id` is by definition unique so it just adds bulk to the style sheet and slows the selector matching down to use selectors like: `section#company div#companyInfo` when `#company #companyInfo` accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Yeah sorry nesting in .less can make things unnecessarily long.  The reason is it increase readability for me when going back and forth between projects.  While removing this could save "bytes" I move towards memorability and readability.  Would you have any idea as to why stellar.js wont work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just saved your website & played around your code. Everything looks fine to me but still there is some problem. So, I removed all your script tags and added jQuery & Stellar from Stellar demo and it works fine.

There is only one bug I found, but I don't know that is the reason for this behaviour. There is a extra comma after `verticaloffset:0`.

```
$(function(){
    $.stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        verticalOffset: 0, /* Remove this comma at the end */
    });
});
```

Comment: That comma will not throw a JS error, but it will be marked as incorrect syntax by a linter or something.

Comment: @AdamWaite Maybe i am not sure but that solved his problem that time...now even the live page is not active..getting a 404.

Comment: Trailing commas break IE http://trailingcomma.com/ - there is a reason for linters to warn on them ;).

Comment: Had the same problem as in the question. The answer helped for me too: The stellar-plugin seems to work only with one or distinct jQuery-versions. Used the jQuery 2.0.2 from the "libs"-directory within the downloaded plugin-directory.

Comment: Please don't use Dropbox or other file lockers here - this is undoubtedly useful if the links last, but they usually do not. Unfortunately the owners of the folders tend to delete them in a tidy-up several years later, which then gives a curator on Stack Overflow some more work to do. (I have removed a file locker link from this answer).