# How to use stellar.js ( jquery plugin for scrolling )?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, scroll, parallax

i have three div in the body:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

All i want to realize is that the "#b" scrolls faster than the other two. That's it.

So i write code like (then revise it according to Mark's suggestion):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).stellar();
   });
</script>

<style>
   #wrap{overflow:hidden;}
</style>

  ...
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
     <div id="a" data-stellar-ratio="1"></div>
     <div id="b" data-stellar-ratio="2"></div>
     <div id="c" data-stellar-ratio="1"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But the result is terrible. I can never scroll to the bottom of the entire page.

**Every time the #b reaches to the top of the window, the entire page runs to the top(just like what i see when first running this page)**

I think i still don't understand what the introduction on stellar.js site means.

Please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Stellar.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025906/how-to-use-stellar-js)

Comment: Please provide tested HTML code next time, there are a lot of `-` syntax errors in your examples.

Comment: yeah i would like to,but there is no stellar.js for the online test tool.

Comment: You can always use something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with jQuery, then paste the code for Stellar.js into the JS pane.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:** To show how your example is supposed to work, [I've created a demo for you on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tM2jf/).

Currently, you're using Stellar.js against 'body', when it needs to be pointed at the scrolling element. For most cases, this is 'window'. Also, you can't use Stellar.js until after the document is ready.

So, you should change your JavaScript to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).stellar();
});
```

jQuery has a shorthand for $(document).ready, and Stellar.js has a shorthand for $(window).stellar, so you could also write it like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.stellar();
});
```

Hopefully this should clear things up for you.

Comment: Thank you markdalgleish, the problem i have is that I can never scroll to the bottom of the entire page. even with your code.